# Foreach skipping a control on usercontrol

Tags: c#, foreach, user-controls

I have a usercontrol, with a panel, called panel1. I added it in designer view.
After choosing an option from combobox, in this case I add two labels to the usercontrol (`mainAspects` has two strings):

```
private void CreateLabelsForMainAspetcs(List<string> mainAspects)
    {
        int mainCount;
        int firstLabelX;
        int firstLabelY;
        int addToFirstLabelY = 0;

        mainCount = mainAspects.Count;
        firstLabelX = 22;
        firstLabelY = 149;

        for (int i = 0; i < mainCount; i++)
        {
                Label mainAsp = new Label();
                mainAsp.Text = mainAspects[i];
                mainAsp.Location = new Point(firstLabelX, firstLabelY + addToFirstLabelY);
                mainAsp.AutoSize = true;
                Controls.Add(mainAsp);
                addToFirstLabelY = addToFirstLabelY + 100;
        }
    }
```

After, when user chooses an other option from combobox, I would like to dispose the labels with this code:

```
 foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is Label)
                    ctrl.Dispose();
            }
```

and create the new ones with `CreateLabelsForMainAspetcs(List<string> mainAspects)`.
But the foreach loop only go through panel1 and first label, after it exits (skipping the second label).

I have checked how many controls has the usercontrol with `this.Controls.Count.ToString()`  before the foreach loop: it says, the uc has 3 controls (with `GetType()` function i found one panel and two labels - so it finds every control).

So after the second run of `CreateLabelsForMainAspetcs(List<string> mainAspects)` there is not 3, but 4 controls. 1 panel, and 3 labels.

After, if I want only one lable to display: run the dispose code and the createlabel with one string in the List - there is only one label on the usercontrol, the second disappers. But the `Controls.Count` says that there is 4 controls - 1 panel and 3 labels. Can you help, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am wrong to assume that the call to dispose do nothing? Since there is still a reference in Controls to the label you want to dispose? Maybe remove the label from Controls then dispose of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that disposing those labels while iterating through `Controls` collection tampers with collection and because of that stops iterating on first disposed Label.

Why don't you try to add them to `List<Label>` instead of disposing. When all Label controls are added to List, loop through that list and remove them.

So, instead of

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is Label)
        ctrl.Dispose();
}
```

try

```
List<Label> labelList = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
foreach(Label lbl in labelList)
{
    lbl.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option one: can you use a ListBox in your control: if yes then use a ListBox in the UC and maintain a List in your parent and set the UC ListBox.source as the list. This should update automatically as you adjust the list

Option Two
make a default view (Usercontrol.Clear()) procedure, call it first than run your code to add new labels.
this call can be blind to the user or you can force the clear call